# <echo> ant task equivalent in rakefile?

Tags: ruby, ant, echo, rakefile

What is the equivilent to the <echo> ant task in a ruby rake file?

Comment: If you were so kind to tell us what an `<echo>` task *is*, I'm sure, there is an equivalent in Rake.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rakefiles are just ruby files.  You can print output with `puts`.